# jquery datatable fixed column creates extra header

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im having a problem with using the FixedColumn plugin with jquery Datatables. When I set the left most column to be fixed, the datatable creates an extra header in the body table.

Hopefully this image can give you a better idea of what I'm taking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWsme.jpg

I have followed the datatable documentation exactly, and I'm totally out of ideas.

Comment: Code is worth a thousand images :) You should post your code, so people have a chance for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

use `scollXInner:true` instead of `scollX:true`. This might helps u.